# Rails output html after evaluating each value in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am writing a helper method for my rails views. After evaluating each value in an array I want to output a button to the html. However, 'puts' is not working and 'return' will work only for one value and end the operator there only.

```
def show_power_buttons
    levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

    levels.each do |level|
        count = @player.powers.where(level: level).count
        if count > 0
            puts (link_to level, '#', :class => 'btn btn-primary')
        end
    end
end
```

I know I am missing something very obvious but unable to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`each` returns `array` on which you have called it, it does not return result of the block.

You can use `map` to make this work

```
def show_power_buttons
  levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  levels.map do |level|
    count = @player.powers.where(level: level).count        
    (link_to level, '#', :class => 'btn btn-primary') if count > 0
  end.compact.join('\n').html_safe
end
```

`compact` will discard all `nil` values, we then use `join` because this is still array, you can join it or can use it this way and in your `view` just say:

```
def show_power_buttons
  levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

  levels.map do |level|
    count = @player.powers.where(level: level).count        
    (link_to level, '#', :class => 'btn btn-primary') if count > 0
  end.compact # returns array of string that are links
end

<%= show_power_buttons.each do |pw| %>
  <%= pw.html_safe %>
<% end %>
```

You have to use html safe, because it will convert string to html

Comment: Yes, you are right I'll have to use html_safe. Any reason to use 'map' over pushing directly to array like in the other answer?

Comment: `map` is more cleaner, because it is meant for this. Map array that it contains the element you desire http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Array.html#method-i-map

Comment: @Hacktacus you don't need to initialize and fill array manually. Why do you ever want to use 2 variables, when 1 is enough?

Answer (score 1):

Collect the return value and return it at the end of the method:

```
def show_power_buttons
    levels = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    retval = []
    levels.each do |level|
        count = @player.powers.where(level: level).count
        if count > 0
            retval << link_to level, '#', :class => 'btn btn-primary'
        end
    end
    return retaval 
end
```

It will output the arrach of links.